# Correct Sculpting Workflow for Animating Mouth and Eyelids / Human (and Animals)

Tags: modeling, animation, sculpting, workflow, remesh

I've recently tried to sculpt a Human Mesh. I was wondering, however, to approach the mouth/eyelids part of the head.
I want to animate this mesh and I will obviously Retopo the whole thing. The character will talk - open his mouth to show teeth and tongue and the eyelids will close/open. The camera will be very close to the character so I can't just fake it.

The model I've created has an eye socket and a mouth socket scultped inside but if I try to remesh it It requires me to go to absurdly low level of voxel size otherwise the space between the lips for example will be meshed together.

I cannot afford to go this low in voxel size since I'm doing a full body so what should my approach be?
Should I Just get the external part and then, once I've retopologied I need to box model the inside socket?

What is the best plan of action? Thank You :D

ps: I've attached a reference image of my mesh. It's not important but this is my current sculpted situation.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you search youtube for "blender character animation shape keys"

Comment: I'm guessing that by "voxels" you mean vertices? And are you talking about the side-effects of the simplification of your mesh once you reduce the vertices/polygons?

Comment: Thank you! I will look onto it

Yes! The Voxel size affect the number of vertices in my model (as I've understood, at least x) . Regarding the side-effects I can give you an example. I have a low poly head with an internal mouth socket (where I would put teeth and tongue). I've sculpted a pair of lips where the upper lip is close to the lower lip. Remeshing by going for a low number of vertices will cause a merge between the vertices of the upper and lower lips. I can resolve this by going extremely high poly. What is the correct workflow for creating a functioning mouth in a human body?